# not able to install archive ipa over migrated app

Tags: xcode, cordova, ipa

I am getting some weird issue while installing ios app.
I have migrated ios app from one account to another account and then I have installed that app from app store on device.
So now I have to push an update from a new account, so when I build an archive with updated build number I am getting issue which is --

`There was an internal API error.`

[image]

Using cordova for developing apps.
Please help on this !